# How to get an input value right in a MySQL SELECT (Ajax on WordPress)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to use an input field value on a SELECT query, but it's returning as null or as an array.

I got the value with jQuery and I'm trying to use it to do a query with Ajax on WordPress.

My HTML

```
<input name="estado" type="radio" id="some-id" value="some-value">
```

My jQuery

```
$("#col1 input:radio").change(function(){

    var ufname= $(this).val();

    $.post({
        url: "http://192.168.64.2/monsoy/site/variedades/resultados-de-produtividade/estado-variedade",
        type: "POST", 
        data: ufname, 
        success: function(data) {
            $("#col2").html(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log( e);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

My PHP

```
$sSQL = "   SELECT mapa_produtividade_variedade, mapa_produtividade_uf
            FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "mapa_produtividade 
             ";
    $sSQL .= " WHERE mapa_produtividade_uf = '".addslashes(strip_tags($_POST[]))."'";

$sSQL .= " GROUP BY mapa_produtividade_variedade";

  $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sSQL , ARRAY_A );                     
if ($results) : 
foreach($results as $row) : ?>  

echo-results
```

Using `<?php var_dump($_POST['estado']); ?>`, I get NULL.

`<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` will give me

```
  ["MT"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I need just that `MT` for my query (just that two characters), but I can get it without the whole array.

I'm just starting learning PHP, Ajax and MySQL, so I guess I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: `addslashes(strip_tags($_POST[]))`, `$_POST[]` you using the array accessor without supplying a key, if you not providing the data encoded you need to read the raw `php://input` stream,

Comment: If it was me , I'd focus on getting a working sql query first.

Comment: @MartinBarker I tried using the input name, but `<?php var_dump($_POST['estado']); ?>` gave me NULL.

@Strawberry the query was working without the  Ajax part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your using the `$_POST` supper global array without a key, so if your not supplying a key = values to the data in jQuery with  $_POST won't work without being form-encoded key = value.

E.G
`key=value&key2=value2`

So if you're not doing that you need to read the raw `php://input` stream `file_get_contents("php://input");`

The other option is to change `var ufname= $(this).val();` to `var ufname= {val:$(this).val()};` and

```php
$sSQL .= " WHERE mapa_produtividade_uf = '".addslashes(strip_tags($_POST[]))."'";
```

to

```php
$sSQL .= " WHERE mapa_produtividade_uf = '".addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['val']))."'";
```

Also, `addslashes` is not a valid way to escape a string going into SQL, use [Bind Parameters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208306/wpdb-prepare-do-i-have-to-bind-a-parameter-to-the-table-name) or at the very least the built into the [module escapers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_real_escape/), please read: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

and i mean i could use jQuery on your page via the Web Inspector console and run

```php
(function(){
 $.post({
        url: "http://192.168.64.2/monsoy/site/variedades/resultados-de-produtividade/estado-variedade",
        type: "POST", 
        data: "�' OR 1 = 1 /*", 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And that string im sending is in php `chr(0xbf).chr(0x27).' OR 1=1 /*';`